# How to solve the failed verification with zipalign?

Tags: android, release, zipalign

I have a problem with zipalign. I can't go through the proces. Each run ends with `Verification FAILED`. For some files i see something like this

```
2574474 res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png (BAD - 2)
```

for the reset

```
7044070 res/layout/notification_template_media.xml (OK - compressed)
```

The apk is generated but when I upload it via console I receive info that it is not compressed properly. What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like gradle has pushed a new version without the zipalign task. I had the same issue after changing this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

The problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Chen is right. 
When you upgrade your AS, you need to check your build.grade.

`buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}`

check that gradle version is 2.1.2 or not. 
I try 2.2.0-alpha3, and always get zipalign fialed. 
Just downgrade grade version to 2.1.2 
Then solve this problem.

Try it.