# No zipAlignEnabled in gradle2.2.0-alpha3

Tags: android, gradle, zipalign

after I updated my top-level gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

AndroidStudio2.2-Preview3 ignored the zipAlignEnabled-option. In previous gradle-versions the gradle-tab showed a entry in "others" called `zipAlignRelease`, in 2.2.0-alpha3 is the entry missing. 
Does anybody else face this issue and is there a chance to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check out this answer from Chen http://stackoverflow.com/a/37745324/756809

Comment: I have to do a zipalign on the apk manually myself `zipalign -v 4 {APP}.apk {ZIPALIGNED_APP}.apk`.

Comment: @DavidCheung same here..