# Gradlew from command line doesn't create signed APK

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

If I use Android Studio's "Generate Signed APK" from the Build menu it works and generates a signed apk. **The problem is the apk is not generated if I try to run**

```
./gradlew clean build assembleRelease
```

I've configured my build.gradle like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        //set values in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties to sign with your own keystore and certificate
        storeFile file(project.hasProperty("KEYSTORE_FILE") ? KEYSTORE_FILE : "/")
        storePassword project.hasProperty("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD") ? KEYSTORE_PASSWORD : ""
        keyAlias project.hasProperty("KEY") ? KEY : ""
        keyPassword project.hasProperty("KEY_PASSWORD") ? KEY_PASSWORD : ""
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

My gradle.properties file looks like these:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true

KEYSTORE_FILE=/home/user/Documents/programs/keystoreAndroidStudio/keystore.jks
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=xxxxxx yyyyy
KEY=Client
KEY_PASSWORD=xxxxx yyyyy
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried feeding the signing params directly to gradlew but it doesn't work either.

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$KEYFILE -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$STORE_PASSWORD -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

I'm starting to think that it is something related to my passwords containing a space. I tried giving the previous command a wrong password and it didn't complain, it still said BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: Looks like you've done all the correct things from that post... What files are being generated?

Comment: Nothing is being generated. I noticed that when I do it through Android Studio it executes project-b:assembleRelease so I also tried with that through the command line and didn't work.

Comment: You seem to just be running `assembleRelease`, not `project-b:assembleRelease`

Comment: I tried both but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know which gradle version you are using.

**Here is a [page](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/) to get the latest gradle** (I recommend to bookmark this page).

I faced similar gradle issues in the past (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741191/no-zipalignenabled-in-gradle2-2-0-alpha3)), so my advice is: **change the gradle version, clean and rebuild**.

PS: I know that my answer is quite vague, but for me the page (linked above) was often a life-saver, so it can't harm to share this info.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm using  "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'" which I think is the latest stable version but still no luck